# i need to prove/show that there is a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ that $f(y) \geq f(x)$ for every $x \in\mathbb{R}$ (limit usage)

Tags: limits, functions

Let the positive and continuous $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ . Also it is given that

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = 0
$$
I need to prove/show that there is a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ that $f(y) \geq f(x)$ for every $x \in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Assume without loss of generality that $f\neq 0$, and so there is $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0) > 0$. Let $\epsilon = f(x_0)/2$, then there is a $M > 0$ such that
$$
|x| > M \Rightarrow f(x) < \epsilon
$$
(This is because $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x) = 0$)
Choose $M$ large enough so that $x_0 \in [-M,M]$. Now, $f$ is continuous on a compact set $[-M,M]$, so there is $y \in [-M,M]$ such that
$$
f(y) \geq f(x) \quad\forall x \in [-M,M]
$$
And for any $x \notin [-M,M]$, we know that
$$
f(x) < \epsilon = f(x_0)/2 < f(x_0) \leq f(y)
$$